# I initialize fragment properly but it is not showing up after transaction

Tags: java, android, fragment

My code is as follows:-

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager(); 
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction(); 
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, mFeedFragment); 
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null); 
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: Please provide information about mFeedFragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is bit weird but it works.

just add android:background="#FFFFFF" attribute to your root layout of the fragment and it will show properly.
been there done that.

Comment: I'd also add that you should set the `android:focusable="true"` & `android:clickable="true"` attributes to the root layout too or you could potentially click a View component (i.e. button) that's on the previous fragment and face unusual behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Please start by following the best practices, like using Fragment from Support package and using getSupportFragmentManager() instead of getFragmentManager()

Take one step at a time. The above piece of is insufficient for me to provide more information than this.

Answer (score 0):

1) You may be giving wrong handle to the FrameLayout in the view for your activity.

2) You may be mixing Activity, AppCompatActivity, getFragmentManager and getSupportFragmentManager. If your activity is inheriting Activity use getFragmentManager, or if it is using AppCompatActivity use getSupportFragmentManager.